# Python shutil, complete file is not getting written to archive. Tried zipfile also

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, shutil

I have following code:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import binascii
import zipfile

code = "testing111"

head1 = ("\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01")
head2 = ("\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01")
head3 = ("\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01")

evilbuff = bytearray(head1)
evilbuff += code
evilbuff += bytearray(head2)
evilbuff += code
evilbuff += bytearray(head3)

file = "folder\\file\\demo\\images.png"
f = open(file,mode='wb')
f.write(evilbuff)

file2 = sys.argv[2]
shutil.make_archive("myzip", "zip", "demo_03")
print ("[+] Done")
```

I'm trying to write a file in `folder_03\file\demo\` and then zip the contents of `folder_03` folder. Everything is working fine.

There is just one problem. The file `images.jpg` *is stripped at the end*.

It's getting written as expected in `folder\file\demo\images.jpg` but in the zip archive the file is not complete. *Around 300 bytes are stripped from the end*. Is it some bug in the python zip utility? I also tried with zipfile but had the same issue.

The bytes in `head1, head2, head3` here are just examples.

Comment: Isn't the file just getting compressed when it is put in an archive?

Comment: Yes its compressed. But if I extract that archive and check that image file again. Some bytes from last are missing. However the file in the demo filder is written correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the file. Use `f.close()` after you write the file, or even better, use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import binascii
import zipfile

code = "testing111"

head1 = ("\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01")
head2 = ("\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01")
head3 = ("\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01")

evilbuff = bytearray(head1)
evilbuff += code
evilbuff += bytearray(head2)
evilbuff += code
evilbuff += bytearray(head3)

file = "folder\\file\\demo\\images.png"
with open(file, mode='wb') as file_object:
    file_object.write(evilbuff)

file2 = sys.argv[2]
shutil.make_archive("myzip", "zip", "demo_03")
print ("[+] Done")
```

Comment: the image.png is created fine. But after zip the image.png is not complete for some reason